# Create reference data only when EF code first database is initially created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table called "Invoice" and that has a field called "PaymentTypeId" which points to another table called "PaymentType".

Using EntityFramework code first, how do we add reference data such as:

```
PaymentTypeId: 1 | Description: Card
PaymentTypeId: 2 | Description: Cash
PaymentTypeId: 3 | Description: Cheque
```

But only when the database is first created?

I'm aware of the OnModelCreating override and I could select from the table to see if data exists, however; I see that as an extra Db call. Is there something else I can hook into to only insert reference data after inital creating of the database?

This is for an MVC5 application.

PS: Apologies if this has already been answered. Perhaps I'm searching the wrong terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the seed method. In the `Configuration.cs` under `Migrations` folder:

```
protected override void Seed(YourDbContext context)
{
    context.PaymentType.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new PaymentType() { Id = 1, Description= "Card" },
        new PaymentType() { Id = 2, Description= "Cash" },
        new PaymentType() { Id = 3, Description= "Cheque" }
        );    
}
```

Don't forget to add the required namespaces. You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) for details.